# Как правильно писать слово "длин(Н)ющий"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать слово "длин(Н)ющий" - через одно или два Н?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать НН (по орфографическому словарю В.В.Лопатина). Но есть два варианта: длиннУщий и длиннЮщий. Оба приемлемы.

Answer (score 0):

Писать нужно 2 н: к основе прилагательного длин - прибавили суффикс -н-.

Answer (score 0):

Это слово образовано от ДЛИННЫЙ, убираем окончание ЫЙ и прибавляем суффикс ЮЩ+ окончание ИЙ, как в математике.Поэтому НН остаётся.